# How to change the image displayed in the android widget selection dialogue?

Tags: android, widget

How do I change the rendering?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify [the `android:previewImage` attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#preview) in your app widget XML metadata file:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:minWidth="146dip"
  android:minHeight="146dip"
  android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
  android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
  android:autoAdvanceViewId="@+id/words"
  android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
  android:resizeMode="vertical"
/>
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget))

Comment: The previewImage changes the image when I move the widget around on my homescreen, but it doesn't change the image in the list of widgets.

Comment: @user3552325: You may need to reboot your device to have the change take effect, or possibly uninstall and reinstall your app. Home screen implementations may cache this information, forcing you to take more steps to get it to load your new image.

Comment: The image that is display is the default app icon from when I created the project. I have since then changed the icon, but it is still being displayed. I also added android:previewImage="@drawable/emptybar" to the xml file but it isn't loading that image either. I reinstalled the app and rebooted the device. Not just what else to try.

Comment: @user3552325: You can also provide an `android:icon` attribute on the `<receiver>` that is your `AppWidgetProvider`, to override your standard icon. It may be that your home screen is going with that icon, rather than `android:previewImage`, in its app widget chooser.

Comment: I remade the application folder in eclipse and it fixed it.

Comment: For me I have the same problem. It works in the emulator, but on my Nexus 5, in the widget selection list I have just the default android icon. Tried everything, both android:icon in the receiver and the previewimage and uninstall/reinstall, rebooting phone etc, but no matter. Any clues welcome.

Comment: @kabir as far as I remember, the problem was the size of my preview image. It was too big or something. With a preview image the size of 100x100 pixels it worked for me.

Comment: @zaifrun  you are right , i changed the size of preview image and it is working now.My preview image was too small.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, tried everything deleted the old previewImage, uninstall/reinstall app, rebooting device, Sync Project with Gradle Files, Invalidate Caches/Restart, none worked. Finally, I could change it only after changing **applicationId** in **build.gradle** app file.