# Cannot change AppWidget icon from the default

Tags: android, icons, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I have an AppWidget in my app, but I cannot get it to change its icon in the widget drawer.

I set the icon in AndroidManifest

```
<receiver android:name=".MealWidget"
        android:label="AwesomeWidget"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_meals_icon">
```

And set the PreviewImage in the appwidget-provider:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_meals_icon" />
```

But the icon is still the default blue rectangle with "EXAMPLE" written on it. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you fully uninstalled and reinstalled the app? The home screen might be caching the images.

Comment: Uninstalled, restarted the phone, installed again. Still the same.

Comment: On my phone there is still the original image, but on others' phones is the new one. Not really sure how to purge the cached icon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the image displayed in the android widget selection dialogue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650435/how-to-change-the-image-displayed-in-the-android-widget-selection-dialogue)

Comment: I had the same issue, you can find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56694659/9863904).

Answer (score 0):

According to the document this is the way of declaring a widget reciever in manifets.

```
<receiver android:name="ExampleAppWidgetProvider" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```

For more info, refer this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html